# How many signals use even number of blue flags and odd number of black flags?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Question:
>
> There are 48 flags,12 of each colors red,white,blue and black. 12 of these flags are used to send a signal.How many signals use even number of blue flags and odd number of black flags?

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: Does the order of flags in a signal matter?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel It wasn't mentioned ,but I assumed that order does matter as different order could convey a different signal.

Comment: I think you can use generating functions .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are enough flags of each color, it suffices to count "good" strings of arbitrarily length.

Let $T(n)$ denote the number of good strings of length $n$ (so your answer is $T(12)$.

Let $A(n)$ be the number of strings of length $n$ with an even number of blues, and an even number of black.

Let $B(n)$ be the number of strings of length $n$ with an odd number of blues and an odd number of blacks.

Let $C(n)$ denote the strings of length $n$ with an odd number of blues and an even number of blacks

Then $$A(n)=2A(n-1)+C(n-1)+T(n-1)\quad B(n)=2B(n-1)+C(n-1)+T(n-1)$$ $$C(n)=2C(n-1)+A(n-1)+B(n-1)$$ $$ T(n)=2T(n-1)+A(n-1)+B(n-1)$$

We have initial conditions $$A(1)=2\quad B(1)=0\quad C(1)=1\quad T(1)=1$$

Barring error (definitely possible) this yields $$T(12)=\fbox {4194304}$$

Consistency check (for implementation):  As every string of length $n$ is exactly one of these types we must have $A(n)+B(n)+C(n)+T(n)=4^n$.

Comment: Could you please explain how you got the recurrence relations?

Comment: Well, take $A(n)$.  Suppose $A$ is a string in $A(n)$ and let $A'$ be the string of length $n-1$ you get by removing the last character in $A$.  If that last character was red or white, then $A'\in A(n-1)$ (hence the $2\times A(n-1)$ term).  If the last character was blue then $A'\in C(n-1)$.  If the last character was black then $A'\in T(n-1)$. The others are similar.

Comment: Just to stress, this method won't work, or at least won't work so easily, if the character limits get involved.  Here, since there are $12$ of each color, I can use each color has often as I like.  But if, say, there were only $3$ red ones then I couldn't get such simple formulas.